# in web-audio api how to obtain an array(eg. FLOAT32 array) from a stream (eg a microphone stream) for several seconds

Tags: web-audio-api, web-mediarecorder

I would like to fill an array from a stream for around ten seconds.{I wish to do some processing on the data)So far I can:

(a) obtain the microphone stream using mediaRecorder

(b) use analyser and  analyser.getFloatTimeDomainData(dataArray) to obtain an array but it is size limited to only a little over half a second of data.I can also successfully output the data after processing back onto a stream and to outDestination.

(c) I have also experimented with obtaining a 'chunks' array from mediaRecorder directly but the problem then is that I can't find any mime type that would give me a simple array of values - ie an uncompressed sample by sample single channel set of value - ie a longer version of 'dataArray' in (b).

I am wondering if I am missing a simple way round this problem?

Solutions I have seen tend to use step (b) and do regular polls then reassemble a longer array - however it seems the timing is a bit tricky ..

I'v also seen suggestions to use audio workouts - I might have to do this but would prefer a simpler solution!

Or again, if someone knows how to drive mediaRecorder to output the chunks array in a simple array format  FLOAT32.of one channel.That would do the trick.

Or maybe I'm missing something simpler?

I have code showing those steps that have been successful and will upload if anyone requests.

Comment: In the lingo of digital audio, you want a PCM representation of your audio ... a sequence of voltage samples that can be sent to a speaker. MediaRecord does not generate that, but rather generates a compressed representation. I think you'll need the web audio API and an [AudioWorkletNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioWorkletNode).

Comment: Thanks: indeed I've started looking at the worklet approach. I found the site: [https://googlechromelabs.github.io/web-audio-samples/audio-worklet/](https://googlechromelabs.github.io/web-audio-samples/audio-worklet/) helpful.